# Associating Devise user with Stripe subscriptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, strip

The Railscast about Stripe uses a subscription model. When setting up Devise one sets up a user model. What should we do when using Stripe with Devise? Should I setup an association between the User (has_one) and the Subscription? Should I setup the subscription info in the User? Which option is better for the long term as an application grows?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. (you knew this was coming)

If you want to allow multiple subscriptions, or complex billing scenarios where a user can have access a couple of different ways, then have the subscription be its own object.

If every user has 1 billing setup, like your app always has 1 credit card per user, then have it be attributes on your user.